# jquery draggable -- animate "clone" on drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I'm building a widget which allows user to copy items from one list over to another, but dragging.

I've figured out the helper: 'clone' option will allow me to drag a copy of my draggable, rather than the draggable itself. I'd like to have the clone animate/snap in to place when I drop it on my droppable, but it seems to be destroyed as soon as I release it. How can I prevent its destruction so I can animate it myself when it's released?

I realize Sortable might give me some of the functionality I want, but then my lists will become sortable, which I don't want. I just want simple copy -> release - > snap functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the callback function for drop, do something like:

```
draggedElement.clone().appendTo(dropDestination);
```

Let me know if that's not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question on [Doctype](http://doctype.com/jqueryui-animate-clone-drop#answer_3662) which included [this demo](http://pastebin.me/c754509741569a3708d94d65878db13d). It uses draggable and droppable though, and not sortable as you described in your question. I wasn't sure which one you are using, but the method to animate the clone is similar.

Comment: not in above scenario but in other scenario it helped me, thanks